# Chaining jQuery animations that affect different elements

Tags: jquery, animation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div2").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div3").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#div4").delay(8000).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

This is my current setup but I feel like this isn't the best way to write this. I can't find any examples on how you would write this better for timing. Any help? I'd appreciate it.

I should also add that the timing of each element isn't consistent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`fadeIn` takes a callback as its second parameter.  That callback is executed as soon as the animation is complete.  If you want the elements to fade in sequentially, you could chain the callbacks:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").fadeIn("slow", function(){
        $("#div2").fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $("#div3").fadeIn("slow", function(){
                $("#div4").fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This could be re-written using an array of selectors and a single method, if you felt like it:

```
var chain = function(toAnimate, ix){
    if(toAnimate[ix]){
        $(toAnimate[ix]).fadeIn('slow', function(){ chain(toAnimate, ix + 1 )});
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    chain(['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4'], 0);
});
```

[See this last one in action at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/epuvu4/edit).

Comment: This was the solution I was about propose, except that I don't understand why you repeat the #div4 fadeIn at the bottom. Is that just a typo?

Comment: While this is valid, I believe the point of the OP's delay is to create the sequential behavior based on how long the animation would take. With that, the delay references could be ripped out, since it will take place sequentially via the callback now

Answer (score 12):

This can be done elegantly since 1.8:

```
$("div").toArray().map(function(e){
    return function(){
        return $(e).fadeIn(600).promise()
    };
}).reduce(function( cur, next ){
    return cur.then(next);
}, $().promise());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f3WzR/

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I'd do it in a loop, as long as you're talking about a consistent increment (and as long as they appear in the same order on the page).

```
$("#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4").each(function( idx ) {
    $(this).delay( idx * 1000 ).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/km66t/

This uses the index passed by `.each()` to increment the delay.

So you're effectively doing:

```
$("#div1").delay( 0 ).fadeIn("slow");
$("#div2").delay( 1000 ).fadeIn("slow");
$("#div3").delay( 2000 ).fadeIn("slow");
$("#div4").delay( 3000 ).fadeIn("slow");
```

---

**EDIT:** To hopefully address the issue in the comment below, you could instead store an Array of the delays you want to use, and access the proper index of the Array using the index from `.each()`.

```
var delays = [0, 1000, 2000, 4000];

$("#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4").each(function( idx ) {
    $(this).delay( delays[ idx ] ).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: What if I didn't want it consistent?

Comment: @Tom - Are you saying you would like them to be random, or would you have a set of specific delays you would want. Also, would you want the duration of the animation to be random or varying? I'll give an update in anticipation of your reply.

Comment: @patrick - I'm a designer trying to code. =] I want specific timing for affected elements. I was looking for an optimal way to write this. What I wrote(which I edited to make it more clear) seemed sloppy but it may have been the only solution...

Comment: @Tom - I do see a consistency in the durations. Each subsequent duration is a multiple of 4 of the previous (except for the first). Is this a pattern or just a coincidence?

Comment: @patrick - Haha, that's was a coincidence but I do praise your attentiveness. I think the solution you have now will work perfectly for me to adjust timings with that array. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: @Tom - You're welcome. :o) Note also that you can shorten it a bit if you give each of those elements a common class, then select using that class instead of the ID. So if they all had a class called `"toFadeIn"` (or something), you could select them with `$("div.toFadeIn").each(...`.

Answer (score 0):

Not happy with the provided answers, here is what i used:

```
    var $steps = $('#div1, #div2, #div3');
    // iterate throught all of them
    $.each($steps,function(index,value){
        $stage.fadeIn('slow', function(){
            // You can even do something after the an animation step is completed placing your code here.
            // run the function again using a little introspection provided by javascript
            arguments.callee
        });  
    })
```

This way you don't have to declare the delays.