# jQuery function chaining unrelated objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have of course searched SO for an answer to my 'specific' question but haven't found anything that allows me to reach my desired goal. Basically, I'd like to be able to chain together function calls with the ability to add a 'delay' between those calls being issued. I'm figuring that something along the lines of a `setTimeout()` chain will be required. However, as these calls are asynchronous, I obviously can't simply chain those together and hope for a result. I did see reference to the built in jQuery queue and dequeue functions and figured that something might work based on that. Thus far, I've not been able to concoct anything that gets close to my requirement.

I've created a very basic example that demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve by chaining here (btw - jsfiddle is being a bit slow today):

http://jsfiddle.net/jimibt/wZeTT/

this uses nested setInterval calls, therefore is nasty and doesn't scale. My nirvana would be a jquery extension method that had the following syntax (1st param being the function, 2nd param being the setTimout value delay):

```
$().chain($('#strap1').fadeIn(1300), 500)
     .chain($('#strap2').fadeIn(1300), 500)
     .chain($('#strap3').fadeIn(1300), 500)
     .start();
```

Now I know that there is a delay() function in jquery, but this only works (to my knowledge) as part of a chain against a single selector and thus can't be used to chain together multiple unconnected elements as per my example. I did see this linked SO question that is CLOSE to what I was hoping for, but still not wrapped up in the way I'd like:

[Chaining jQuery animations that affect different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198091/chaining-jquery-animations-that-affect-different-elements)

Any thoughts?

Comment: That syntax can't work. The `fadeIn` call would be done before the `chain` call, so it couldn't be delaied by the second parameter. You would have do do something like `.chain(function(){ $('#strap1').fadeIn(1300) }, 500)` to make that work.

Comment: ok, syntax issues aside, i get that and would love to see that in action :) and in fact, wonder that the generic extension wouldn't 'wrap' the function(){} around the parameter

Answer (score 3):

You can use callbacks like this

```
$('#strap1').delay(500).fadeIn(1300,function(){
    $('#strap2').delay(500).fadeIn(1300,function(){
        $('#strap3').delay(500).fadeIn(1300);
    });
});
```

**Usage** <sup>*[[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/wZeTT/1/)*</sup>

```
$('#strap1').delay(500).fadeIn(1300,function(){
    $('#strap2').delay(500).fadeIn(1300,function(){
        $('#strap3').delay(500).fadeIn(1300, function() {
            $('#strapline').css({
                'color': '#fff'
            }).animate({
                'color': color
            }, 3000);            
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: starx - yup have been tredding this water for a while now and am looking for the nirvana single chaining method. again, thanks and +1

Comment: @jimtollan, Chaining occurs at a particular object at a time. I dont think there is any other way. BTW, I have updated with the usage and demo of your fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `delay` and `queue` methods to chain animations:

```
$('#strap1').delay(500).fadeIn(1300).queue(function(){
    $('#strap2').delay(500).fadeIn(1300).queue(function(){
        $('#strap3').delay(500).fadeIn(1300);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/8QZcN/

Comment: thanks guffa, i had done something along those lines in my 'journey' but am hoping to put together something a little more generic in nature. +1 all the same!! :-)